# getting list of mp3 files from a sdcard in the order they were added in the card

Tags: android

hi 
i am developing an android app using an emulator.
i am using a filter class to filter mp3 songs and adding these to a list songs.

```
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter 
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
    {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
}
public void updateList() 
   {
       File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
       if (home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) 
       {
           for (File file : home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter())) 
           {
            songs.add(file.getName());

           }

       }        
   }
```

i want to know is there any order in which new songs gets added in sdcard like 
alphabetically or datewise because i am seeing that new songs getting added anywhere
thus each time i am adding any songs i am finding my song list rearranged.

is there any way to get the list of all songs form the sdcard in the order of dates&time 
they were added in the card ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `File` class exposes the creation date, but you could use the `lastModified()` method to find out when the files were last modified, then sort the list based on that value.

Comment: i did some tasks of  addition and deletion of files in my android emulator and found that unlike PC new files gets added randomly in any order with old files..that's strange.anyway i am doin my task in a different way.thanks 4 info